# Continuity of a specific Power Series

Tags: continuity, power-series

I have given the following question: Argue that $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$. $F$ is given by
$$
F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{-n}z^{2n+1}}{n!}
$$
In a previous exercise we have found that the convergence of radius $R=\infty$. To argue that $F$ is continuous i have used the following sentence: Let $R\in[0,\infty]$ be the convergence of radius for the power series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$. Then the power series' sumfunction is continuous in $\{w\in\mathbb{C}: |w-a|<R\}$

Is it enough to argue that because $R\in[0,\infty]$ then $F$ is continuous as the sentence then is aplied.

Comment: Well done, Benjamin!

Comment: Thank you, Mathias!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when $R=\infty$, $\{w:|w-a|<R\}$ is the entire complex plane. Hence there is continuity at all points.